# How to put multiple JTextfields on different lines in the center of BorderLayout?

Tags: java

So firstly, I added the text fields and their labels into separate panels as I wanted them to be in line with each other, I added them via Flow layout;

```
        //add them in Flow Layout
        panel.add(label_1);panel.add(file_name);
        pane2.add(label_2);pane2.add(h_link);
        pane3.add(label_3);pane3.add(pages);
```

What i wanted to do next is to add them using BorderLayout in a way that all of them will be in the center of the window. Additionally, I wanted to add submit button of the details;

```
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, pane2);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, pane3);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, submit);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

As I am writing this post, I did not achived the result that i wanted , the screenshot attached shows the resulting frame which is not I wanted. 
By all means, if you have also any suggestions for how to do it more efficiently please do share.

[image]

Comment: I can't find the attached screenshot, but there can only be ONE component at each *position* (e.g. CENTER) of a BorderLayout. Use a GridLayout (or GridBagLayout, BoxLayout, ...) eventually in a nested JPanel (Obs: there is no need for `getContentPane()` anymore)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to solving this is to ***nest*** `JPanels`, each using its own layout, thereby allowing you to effectively *nest* layouts:

- Place a `JPanel` in the `BorderLayout.CENTER position`
- Give the `JPanel` a `GridLayout`, one allowing multiple rows and one column, e.g., `new GridLayout(0, 1)`
- Add your `JTextField`s to the `JPanel`

---

Another approach is to simply use a JTable, one with a single column and multiple rows.

---

Another approach -- if you're trying to gain input from a user in a JLabel/JTextField grid -- is to use GridBagLayout to space the components nicely together